# How to schedule IE page reload

Tags: javascript, refresh

Is there a mechanism i can use to force page reload every 'n' minutes? I can't modify the page code itself, "refresh" request should be issued from outside of the page itself

Comment: outside of the page from where?

Comment: correct. outside of the page. perhaps another page can forse a page reload or a script on a computer

Comment: no... I mean are you talking about a userscript like with greasemonkey or what? If you want to use javascript it has to be in the page somewhere or injected into it.

Comment: @Joseph .. hmm greasemonkey is an interesting idea. does it work for IE? Thought that this plugin was for FF only

Comment: Yes that only works on FF, Chrome, Opera (pretty much anything but IE).  For IE the best you can practically do is create a bookmarlette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timedRefresh = setTimeout(function(){location.reload(true)},1*60000)
```

That will refresh the page every minute. If you make it into a script for greasemonkey it will continually be injected into the page and keep executing every minute + load time.

ANother way is to, as suggested, put the page in an iframe. e.g.

```
if (self == top){
document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe id="meh" src="' + location.href + '" width="100%" height="100%">';
var t = setInterval("document.getElementById('meh').src = location.href", 1000);
}
```

That has only been tested in Chrome however, and innerHTML may pose some problems with IE. (not sure though)

Comment: Is this plugin available for IE? (Greasemonkey)

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting the site within an iframe and refreshing that via Javascript at set intervals.

For a more simple solution, depending on your actual needs, I have used the following site for something similar:

http://www.lazywebtools.co.uk/cycler.html

Answer (score 0):

The wollowing works well. Replace "cnn.com" with the page you need to reload and "10" with the interval in seconds

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />

  <title>Some title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="10" />
</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style=
  "width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
this method will reload the page after every 1 minute

```
setInterval(function () {  window.location.reload(); }, 60000);
```