# How can I get to use auto refresh my entire wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have tried many plugin and tried many times but failed to do.

In the force refresh plugin, I tried but this not worked automatic. If i click to refresh user then it works otherwise it not works.

Can You help me to do the best?

I need entire website all post & page not a single page or post

Comment: So you want every page on the website to automatically reload without user interaction, after a certain delay?

Comment: Yes, I want, but how can I get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule IE page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864931/how-to-schedule-ie-page-reload)

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin to (or do so in some other manner) add a header or footer to every page.

In the header or footer use JavaScript to reload the page periodically with the following code.

```
<script>
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: I have added but no changes, help me rangpurdaily.com

Comment: You have added it without the <script></script> tags. You need to have <script> tags around it for it to work.